# Karate : Dynamic text value in xml file

Tags: karate

I want to provide dynamic values in the XML

test.xml:

```
<name>
 <first>#(first)</first>
 <last>#(last)</last>
 <version>this is the #(version) in the file</version>
</name>
```

I have a .csv file:

first,last,version

abc,pqr,1

lma,qwe,2

Feature file:
call the csv and xml file

For first and last variable it works but for version it doesn't take version value

Comment: may be a bug, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - also search other answers https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+csv+xml

Comment: @PeterThomas The parameter in xml file works when the Value of a tag has to be dynamic like it works when we have like this <first>#(first)</first> but when the value of a tag has text with dynamic value it does not work like for  <version>this is the #(version) in the file</version>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, changing the tag name (or key name in JSON) is an advanced operation which "embedded expressions" cannot be used for. I think you should just use XPath. You should also take some time to read the examples linked from the documentation.

Here is just one way to do it, there are many more:

```
Scenario Outline:
* def payload =
"""
<name>
 <first>#(_first)</first>
 <last>#(_last)</last>
</name>
"""
* set payload /name/version = _version
* match payload == <name><first>foo</first><last>bar</last><version>1</version></name>

Examples:
| _first | _last | _version |
| foo    | bar   | 1        |
```